# How to convert a Parallel.Foreach in C# to F#?

Tags: f#

I have been trying to convert some C# to F# and it hasn't been going so good as I am relatively new to F#

Here is the working C# snippet:

```cs
static void doParallelForeach()
{
    // The sum of these elements is 40.
    int[] input = { 4, 1, 6, 2, 9, 5, 10, 3 };
    int sum = 0;

    Parallel.ForEach(
        input, 
        () => 0,   
        (n, loopState, localSum) => 
        {
            localSum += n;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread={0}, n={1}, localSum={2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, n, localSum);
            return localSum;
        },
        (localSum) => Interlocked.Add(ref sum, localSum)
    );
}
```

Here is the F# snippet that gives this compiler error: No overloads match for method 'ForEach'.

```ml
let doParallelForeach =

let input:int[] = [|4; 1; 6; 2; 9; 5; 10; 3|]

let sum = 0

Parallel.ForEach

(
    input,

    (fun ()-> 0),

    (fun (n, loopState, localSum) ->
        localSum += n
        Console.WriteLine("Thread={0}, n={1}, localSum={2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, n, localSum);
        return localSum),

    (fun (localSum) -> Interlocked.Add(ref sum, localSum))

)
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried checking for List or Seq iter/map ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of problems with your code.  Here's a literal translation:

```
let doParallelForeach() =
    let input:int[] = [|4; 1; 6; 2; 9; 5; 10; 3|]
    let sum = ref 0

    Parallel.ForEach (
            input,
            (fun ()-> 0),
            (fun n loopState localSum->
                let localSum = localSum + n
                Console.WriteLine("Thread={0}, n={1}, localSum={2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, n, localSum)
                localSum),
            (fun (localSum) -> Interlocked.Add(sum, localSum) |> ignore))
```

Notes:

1. Since your C# code uses a method, I've made `doParallelForeach` into a function instead of a value of type `unit`.
2. `return` and `+=` aren't valid F# code.  You don't need to use `return` in F#, and you can only modify mutable values (and even then, there are no compound assignment operators).  Instead, we just shadow `localSum` with a new value.
3. You're using `ref` incorrectly - it is a function in F#, not a modifier, and it is used to define new reference values, not to extract addresses to pass to methods.  Furthermore, since `sum` was a let-bound immutable value, you couldn't take its address anyway.  The correct way to do this is to use F#'s `ref` function to make `sum` an instance of the `int ref` type.
4. In F#, you use curried (as opposed to tupled) function definitions when defining a delegate.  That is, you use `fun n loopState localSum -> ...` instead of `fun (n, loopState, localSum) -> ...`.

Note that regardless of these fixes, this is a weird method - the results are kept in a local variable (`sum`) which isn't ever exposed to the caller...

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does clear up some things. As you can see, I am still learning the ropes. Yes. It is  weird method. I removed much of the necessary code.